# Parsing nested json data in Android

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have this json

```
{
"where":"{}",
"expiry":1451606400,
"data":{
    "alert":"alert_message",
    "names":["john","paul","frank","bill"],
    "action":"com.fidelizacion.UPDATE_STATUS"
}
```

}

and  in my android app i parsed the json data like this :

```
    String action = intent.getAction();
          String channel = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Channel");
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data"));


          Iterator itr = json.keys();
          while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String key = (String) itr.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "..." + key + " => " + json.getString(key));

          }
```

and the log display

```
action => com.fidelizacion.UPDATE_STATUS
alert => alert_message
names => ["john","paul","frank","bill"]
```

but i want to declare an array with the names  that i receive. any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a JSONArray object:

```
JSONArray arr = json.getJSONArray("names");
int len = arr.length();
String[] names = new String[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    names[i] = arr.getString(i);
}
```